# How can I scroll down to a focused text input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to figure out how can I scroll up/down to the recently focused input.
I am using this text input -> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput

This is the text input:

```
           <TextInput
              autoFocus
              style={PassengersStyles.SearchBox}
              onChangeText={text => searchParamActionHandler(text)}
              value={searchParam}
              placeholder="Search..."
              autoCapitalize="none"
              ref={this.searchRef}
            />
```

It is a hidden text input, it has `autoFocus` so when the input is shown, it is focused right away but the phone-screen/UI stays in the same position. I need that once the input if focused the screen scrolls to the input so the user is able to see that there is a new element in the UI.

Any ideas?

Comment: Adding some code which shows the parent(or enclosing tags) of your textinput would help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing a `<ScrollView>` which is required if your content exceeds the screen height.

You might also need a `KeyboardAvoidingView` which ensures that the `TextInput` is not covered(or hidden) behind the keyboard.

Here I have added a few `<View>`'s to simulate some content.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  KeyboardAvoidingView
} from "react-native";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
        <ScrollView>
          <View
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
            }}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
            }}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
            }}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
            }}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
            }}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
            }}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
            }}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
            }}
          />
          <TextInput
            autoFocus
            placeholder="Textinput far below..."
            style={{ height: 20, backgroundColor: "red" }}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
            }}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
            }}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
            }}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: InputScroll]